# show/hide div when input field is empty(jquery, javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` with content, hide on default and I want to show it, when user input, in the input field which is `#control`.

```
<form>
<input name="control" value="" id="control" />
<div class="show_hide">
  //some content here........
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: **1.** Bind `input` event on the `<input>` **2.** If entered any value in the textbox, show the `<div>` else hide it.

Comment: Use `$('#control').on('input', function(){ ... })`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
// Bind keyup event on the input
$('#control').keyup(function() {
  
  // If value is not empty
  if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
    // Hide the element
    $('.show_hide').hide();
  } else {
    // Otherwise show it
    $('.show_hide').show();
  }
}).keyup(); // Trigger the keyup event, thus running the handler on page load
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name="control" id="control" />
  <div class="show_hide">
    //some content here........
  </div>
</form>
```

On keyup check the value of the input if length is 0 meaning empty hide the div otherwise show

Comment: @Tushar added explanation. Im not good with english so i seldom explain i sometimes dont explain clear enough

Answer (score 4):

Attach `input` event with `#control` as shown :-

```
$('#control').on('input', function(){
   if($.trim(this.value) != "")
      $(this).next('div.show_hide').show();
   else
      $(this).next('div.show_hide').hide();
});
```

**Shorter Versions :-**

```
$('#control').on('input', function(){
    $(this).next('div.show_hide').toggle($.trim(this.value) != "");
});
```

OR

```
$('#control').on('input', function() {
  $(this).next('div.show_hide').toggle(this.value.length > 0);
});
```

OR(adding @Rayon answer in comment here)

```
$('#control').on('input', function(){
    $(this).next('div.show_hide').toggle(!this.value);
});
```

Comment: Will this hide the input if value is `''` ?

Comment: Or just  `$(this).next('div.show_hide').toggle(!this.value);` Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/fq7aduo4/)

Comment: @RayonDabre... i don't think `!this.value` will return `bool`?